# How to display menu items from database

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, facelets

I have two classes representing menu items.

First one is `Category`, it represents the parent menu items.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "category")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Category.findAll", query = "SELECT c FROM Category c"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Category.findByCateId", query = "SELECT c FROM Category c WHERE c.cateId = :cateId"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Category.findByCateName", query = "SELECT c FROM Category c WHERE c.cateName = :cateName")})
public class Category implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "cate_id")
    private Integer cateId;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "cate_name")
    private String cateName;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "category")
    private List<SubCat> subCatList;

    public Category() {
    }

    public Category(Integer cateId) {
        this.cateId = cateId;
    }

    public Category(Integer cateId, String cateName) {
        this.cateId = cateId;
        this.cateName = cateName;
    }

    public Integer getCateId() {
        return cateId;
    }

    public void setCateId(Integer cateId) {
        this.cateId = cateId;
    }

    public String getCateName() {
        return cateName;
    }

    public void setCateName(String cateName) {
        this.cateName = cateName;
    }

    public List<SubCat> getSubCatList() {
        return subCatList;
    }

    public void setSubCatList(List<SubCat> subCatList) {
        this.subCatList = subCatList;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (cateId != null ? cateId.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Category)) {
            return false;
        }
        Category other = (Category) object;
        if ((this.cateId == null && other.cateId != null) || (this.cateId != null && !this.cateId.equals(other.cateId))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "com.entity.Category[cateId=" + cateId + "]";
    }

}
```

Second is `SubCategory`, it represent the child menu items.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "sub_cat")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "SubCat.findAll", query = "SELECT s FROM SubCat s"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "SubCat.findBySubcatid", query = "SELECT s FROM SubCat s WHERE s.subcatid = :subcatid"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "SubCat.findBySubcatName", query = "SELECT s FROM SubCat s WHERE s.subcatName = :subcatName")})
public class SubCat implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "subcatid")
    private Integer subcatid;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "subcat_name")
    private String subcatName;
    @JoinColumn(name = "cat_parent", referencedColumnName = "cate_id")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Category category;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "subCat")
    private List<Items> itemList;

    public SubCat() {
    }

    public SubCat(Integer subcatid) {
        this.subcatid = subcatid;
    }

    public SubCat(Integer subcatid, String subcatName) {
        this.subcatid = subcatid;
        this.subcatName = subcatName;
    }

    public Integer getSubcatid() {
        return subcatid;
    }

    public void setSubcatid(Integer subcatid) {
        this.subcatid = subcatid;
    }

    public String getSubcatName() {
        return subcatName;
    }

    public void setSubcatName(String subcatName) {
        this.subcatName = subcatName;
    }

    public Category getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(Category category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    public List<Items> getItemList() {
        return itemList;
    }

    public void setItemList(List<Items> itemList) {
        this.itemList = itemList;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (subcatid != null ? subcatid.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof SubCat)) {
            return false;
        }
        SubCat other = (SubCat) object;
        if ((this.subcatid == null && other.subcatid != null) || (this.subcatid != null && !this.subcatid.equals(other.subcatid))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "com.entity.SubCat[subcatid=" + subcatid + "]";
    }

}
```

Two class have many to one relationship. I want to display them on my a JSF 2.0/Facelets webpage like:

```
Category 1
    |
    ---->  Sub_Category 1 
    |
    ---->  Sub_Category 2
Category 2
    |
    ---->  Sub_Category 3
    |
    ---->  Sub_Category 4
    . . .
```

How can I do this?

Comment: This is a very open question.  What's your front-end technology, for starters?

Comment: i need help !! please !!

Comment: EJB3 isn't a front end technology. @Joeri understood that you was asking how to *display* a menu in your application. But you seem to actually have trouble with *querying* the `List` with the right menu items from the DB. Still then, your question is too vague. What exactly is the problem you're facing? What happens? What happens not? By the way, your datamodel is a bit overcomplicated. A single table with a `parent_id` column referencing the PK would suffice, as suggested by Narf in his answer.

Comment: Thank you ! my trouble is i dont know how to get list of Category contain sub_cat, i can select list of category and list of sub_category, i want pass category id into sub_category, but they are list data type, how can i pass parameter from list Category to sub_cat?

Comment: @MYE: So, `category.getSubCatList()` isn't returning the desired items?

Comment: Hi BalusC i was do it , but it return {IndirectList: not instantiated} when i use category.subCatList in view (JSF), and when i use category.subCatList.subcatName it return `javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.ServletException: For input string: "subcatName"`

Comment: @MYE: The first case is normal when you do `toString()` on a lazily loaded collection. The second case just indicates that the object type which is returned by `category.subCastList` (thus, a `List`) doesn't have the method `getSubcatName()`. That's correct. You need to invoke the method on a list item instead. E.g. `#{category.subCatList[0].subcatName}` or just iterate over a loop.  Note: when you want to notify someone else automatically about a comment reply, please include `@nickname` in the comment. I only know about your new comment by reading your topic again, not everyone will do this.

Comment: @BalusC if i dont use loop what do i do with getSubcatName()? How? i don't know to return list of it contain between category and subcat

Comment: So, it is working? Your *actual* problem is thus that you don't know how to iterate over them in the view side? You should have made the **actual** problem more clear in the beginning of the question. There's no other solution than just to iterate over them. If you are iterating recursively using include templates, then you need to either make them all the same and single class (as suggested by Narf), or to check the type by `#{item.class.name}`, but that's plain ugly.

Comment: @BalusC do u suggest me merge 2 table to 1 table? but if 2 table it can't do my problem? if it right i will merge it !

Comment: Depends on why you're having trouble with iterating over them in a loop. That's not clear yet.

Comment: @BalusC i don't know what type must it return, E.g. `public type??? medthodA() {  for (int i =0; i < category.getSubcatList.size(); i++){ what's i do?}}`

Comment: Why would you want to do like this? See my answer for an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the comments on the question, you seem to have trouble with displaying them in the view side, which is apparently JSF. As per your question history, you seem to be using JSF2 on Facelets as view technology.

You can just use `ui:repeat` to iterate over the categories and their subcategories. Assuming that you've a managed bean which returns a `List<Category>` by `#{bean.categories}`, here's an example:

```
<ul>
    <ui:repeat value="#{bean.categories}" var="category">
        <li>#{category.cateName}
            <h:panelGroup rendered="#{not empty category.subCatList}">
                <ul>
                    <ui:repeat value="#{category.subCatList}" var="subCat">
                        <li>#{subCat.subcatName}</li>
                    </ui:repeat>
                </ul>
            </h:panelGroup>
        </li>
    </ui:repeat>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a table with 3 columns:

`id int unsigned not null` - id of your menu item
`name <whatever data type you need> not null` - the name of your menu item to display
`parent_id int unsigned default NULL` - id of the parent menu item(if exists)

If `parent_id` is `NULL`, then it's a category.
If `parent_id` is `NOT NULL` then it's a subcategory.
You can use this to create as many menu-levels as you need.

Comment: Hello Narf i know it , but i dont know how to create Dyanmic menu with it, i create method with DataType is List<Category> and get all Category, one method get all Sub_category List<SubCat> and one method get all Item List<Items>, i know i must pass id of Catagory to SubCat for get list of SubCat and pass id of SubCat to items to get list of Items . But DataType return is List how can i pass it into Parameter of each item and subcat?

Comment: Well, I have no experience in Java, so I can't help you with that. I've only replied 'cause you've tagged your question with `database-design`.