# How to generate hierarhical menu from database with heading

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

Is it possible to add the heading for each menu list?

Something like:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
<HeaderTemplate>
 <h3><%# Eval("Country") %><h3>
 <ul>
 </HeaderTemplate>
 <ItemTemplate>
     <li>
         <%# Eval("CityName") %>
     </li>
 </ItemTemplate>                
 </asp:Repeater>
```

So that you have something like:

**Country 1**

```
   City 1
   City 2
```

**Country 2**

```
   City 1
   City 2
```

**Country 3**

```
   City 1
   City 2
```

and so on. This is a single query derived from 2 tables: Countries & Cities.
I could not figure out how. Maybe something like the Java one ( [How to display menu items from database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985904/how-to-display-menu-items-from-database) ) but I am using SQL Server.

Can someone help please!
Many thanks in advance,
Quin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change it so that it is 2 queries and put a repeater within your repeater. Get the country and cities seperately, in your rowdatabound event of the country repeater,  filter the cities to the current country and binf the inner repeater to that.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="RepeaterHeader" runat="server">
<ItemTemplate>
 <h3><%# Eval("Country") %><h3>
 <ul>
 <asp:Repeater ID="RepeaterItem" runat="server">
 <ItemTemplate>
     <li>
         <%# Eval("CityName") %>
     </li>
 </ItemTemplate>               
</asp:Repeater>
</ul>
</ItemTemplate> 
 </asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: Nested repeater is the way to go. Thanks a lot for your response. This is the link that I found based on your suggestion: [link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306154)

Answer (score 1):

ya it is possible, (by the everything is possible).

you can refer to the following website for clear understanding Logic

http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/showasp.asp?filename=demo_repeater1